# Dropping lines of data with pandas increases the memory usage

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a customers dataset that has three columns, a key, and an X and Y representing the customer coordinates.

```
In [1]: customers                                                                              
Out[1]: 
                                         key          X          Y
0       b305b0b7-fb24-4eef-9055-827cf7f39b93        NaN        NaN
1       edf5e4bc-d553-4285-9de3-45165f96dd02   987269.0  6236836.0
2       00ded895-ae97-4d27-b317-91c6931662b7   880460.0  6267799.0
3       d957d117-72db-444f-ac9a-338c2034f5db   830645.0  6287647.0
4       ac504435-7eb8-4275-a3da-6f673ff324ae   837826.0  6293434.0
```

`customers.info()` returns:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 378195 entries, 0 to 378194
Data columns (total 3 columns):
cle    378195 non-null object
X      375850 non-null float64
Y      375850 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2), object(1)
memory usage: 8.7+ MB
```

I only keep data points that have X and Y values (not `NaN`) using:

```
customers2 = customers[customers['X'].notna() & customers['Y'].notna()]
```

Which removes lines with any `NaN` in X or Y (example of index 0).

```
In [2]: customers2                                                                             
Out[2]: 
                                         cle          X          Y
1       edf5e4bc-d553-4285-9de3-45165f96dd02   987269.0  6236836.0
2       00ded895-ae97-4d27-b317-91c6931662b7   880460.0  6267799.0
3       d957d117-72db-444f-ac9a-338c2034f5db   830645.0  6287647.0
4       ac504435-7eb8-4275-a3da-6f673ff324ae   837826.0  6293434.0
5       5d4c8fe0-56ce-4498-a4ee-2fd4314abc1e   987025.0  6427374.0
```

But the info of this new data frame shows a higher memory usage, despite the reduction in the number of entries (from 378195 originally to 375850):

```
In [2]: customers2.info()                                                                       
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 375850 entries, 1 to 378194
Data columns (total 3 columns):
cle    375850 non-null object
X      375850 non-null float64
Y      375850 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2), object(1)
memory usage: 11.5+ MB
```

I can't explain why, even I can continue to manipulate `customers2` like a normal data frame.

Any explanation? Thanks.

Comment: customers2 = customers[(customers['X'].notnull()) &( customers['Y'].notnull())] try this and check size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say your memory index increased because of your Index, before you have:

```
RangeIndex: 378195 entries, 0 to 378194
```

and afterwards:

```
Int64Index: 375850 entries, 1 to 378194
```

the Int64Index takes 8bytes per entry.

This is the RangeIndex: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.RangeIndex.html

You can convert it back like:

`customers2.index = pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=len(customers2), step=1)`